# fetch key value pairs from array objects in sql BigQuery

Tags: sql, parsing, google-bigquery, key-value

I need to parse the column `mapping` and fetch the key value pairs from the second object in array. I would like to create new columns with the fetched data. The data looks like this:

```
row                 mapping 
1       [{'adUnitCode': ca, 'id': 35, 'name': ca}, {'adUnitCode': hd, 'id': 11, 'name': HD}]
2       [{'adUnitCode': bb, 'id': 56, 'name': jk}, {'adUnitCode': hm, 'id': 12, 'name': HM}]
3       [{'adUnitCode': gh, 'id': 78, 'name': ff}, {'adUnitCode': hk, 'id': 13, 'name': HK}]
```

The desired output:

```
row                 adUnitCode                  id                  name
1                     hd                       11                     HD
2                     hm                       12                     HM
3                     hk                       13                     HK
```

Comment: what data type is mapping column?

Comment: Mapping column data type is STRING

Comment: and just to double check - there is no apostrophe around let's say `ca` value? (so it is not valid json from bq prospective)

Comment: No apostrophe. The values are not wrapped in apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one of the approaches (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
select 
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.adUnitCode") as adUnitCode,
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.id") as id,
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.name") as name
from `project.dataset.table`, unnest(
  [json_extract_array(regexp_replace(mapping, r"(: )(\w+)(,|})", "\\1'\\2'\\3"))[safe_offset(1)]]
) as second_object
```

if to apply above to sample data from your question - result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have accepted the answer. What if my array has more than 2 objects? Sometimes it has 4 or 5. It returns all Nulls in this case. How can the query be modified to still grab everything from the 2nd object? The data I need is always in the second object. Thank you in advance.

Comment: query in my answer will always pick second object as long as they are formatted same way as in your question's example. If this is not a case  - please post new question with respective details, examples and we will be happy to further help :o)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, they are formatted the same way, the only difference is that the array can have different number of objects in it. But it is always a second object I need the data from and the format is consistent throughout the dataset. Somehow when I ran the code I have Nulls in return. Anyway, I posted the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336882/fetch-the-data-from-array-of-objects-sql-bigquery with the full example of the sample data.