# fetch the data from array of objects sql BigQuery

Tags: sql, parsing, google-bigquery

I need to fetch key value pairs from the second object in array. Also, need to create new columns with the fetched data. I am only interested in the second object, some arrays have 3 objects, some have 4 etc. The data looks like this:

```
[{'adUnitCode': ca-pub, 'id': 35, 'name': ca-pub}, {'adUnitCode': hmies, 'id': 49, 'name': HMIES}, {'adUnitCode': moda, 'id': 50, 'name': moda}, {'adUnitCode': nova, 'id': 55, 'name': nova}, {'adUnitCode': listicle, 'id': 11, 'name': listicle}]
[{'adUnitCode': ca-pub, 'id': 35, 'name': ca-pub-73}, {'adUnitCode': hmiuk-jam, 'id': 23, 'name': HM}, {'adUnitCode': recipes, 'id': 26, 'name': recipes}]
[{'adUnitCode': ca-pub, 'id': 35, 'name': ca-pub-733450927}, {'adUnitCode': digital, 'id': 48, 'name': Digital}, {'adUnitCode': movies, 'id': 50, 'name': movies}, {'adUnitCode': cannes-film-festival, 'id': 57, 'name': cannes-film-festival}, {'adUnitCode': article, 'id': 57, 'name': article}]
```

The desired output:

```
adUnitCode           id             name 
hmies                49             HMIES
hmiuk-jam            23             HM
digital              48             Digital
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select 
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.adUnitCode") as adUnitCode,
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.id") as id,
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.name") as name
from `project.dataset.table`, unnest(
  [json_extract_array(regexp_replace(mapping, r"(: )([\w-]+)(,|})", "\\1'\\2'\\3"))[safe_offset(1)]]
) as second_object
```

if applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

as you can see, the "trick" here is to use proper regexp in regexp_replace function. I've included now any alphabetical chars and `-` . you can include more as you see needed
As an alternative yo can try `regexp_replace(mapping, r"(: )([^,}]+)", "\\1'\\2'")` as in below example - so you will cover potentially more cases without changes in code

```
#standardSQL
select 
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.adUnitCode") as adUnitCode,
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.id") as id,
  json_extract_scalar(second_object, "$.name") as name
from `project.dataset.table`, unnest(
  [json_extract_array(regexp_replace(mapping, r"(: )([^,}]+)", "\\1'\\2'"))[safe_offset(1)]]
) as second_object
```

Comment: You are an sql magician! The second approach worked for my problem. Thank you so very much! Accepted the answer and voted.

Comment: glad it helped :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thank you for this answer. What would be a way to do this not just for the second object, but for each object?

Comment: @Arsik36 - there is no way to answer this within comments. if you have any question(s) - please post it with all specific details and I will be happy to answer :o) Meantime, if above answer was useful for you - consider voting up :o)

Comment: Thank you, @MikhailBerlyant, I will post my question now once I am done working on it

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant just posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533836/google-big-query-how-to-query-specific-information-from-a-json-column

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: @Arsik36 - sure. will check shortly. meantime, consider voting up this answer if it helped you anyhow :o)

Comment: Happily upvoted as this gave me some insights