# How to query specific information from a JSON column?

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have searched Stack Overflow to get an answer to my question, but while I found many interesting cases, none of them quite address mine.

I have a column called `fields` in my data, that contains JSON information, such as presented below:

```
Row      Fields
 1       [{"label":"Label 1","key":"label_1","description":"Value of label_1"},{"label":"Label 2","key":"label_2","error":"Something"}]
 2       [{"description":"something","label":"Row 1","key":"row_1"},{"label":"Row 2","message":"message_1","key":"row_2"}]
```

In essence, I have many rows of JSON that contain `label` and `key`, and bunch of other parameters like that. From every {}, I want to extract only `label` and `key`, and then (optional, but ideally) stretch every `label` and `key` in every {} to its own row. So, as a result, I would have the following output:

```
Row       Label          Key
 1       Label 1       label_1
 1       Label 2       label_2
 2        Row 1         row_1
 2        Row 2         row_2
```

Please note, contents of `label` and `key` within JSON can be anything (strings, integers, special characters, a mix of everything, etc. In addition, `key` and `label` can be anywhere in relation to other parameters within each {}.

Here is the Big Query SQL dummy data for convenience:

```
SELECT '1' AS Row, '[{"label":"Label 1","key":"label_1","description":"Value of label_1"},{"label":"Label 2","key":"label_2","error":"Something"}]' AS Fields 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS Row, '[{"description":"something","label":"Row 1","key":"row_1"},{"label":"Row 2","message":"message_1","key":"row_2"}]' AS Fields
```

I have first thought of using REGEX to isolate all the brackets and only show me information with `label` and `key`. Then, I looked into BQ Documentation of JSON functions and got very stuck on json_path parameters, specifically because their example doesn't match mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select `row`, 
  json_extract_scalar(el, '$.label') label,
  json_extract_scalar(el, '$.key') key
from your_table, unnest(json_extract_array(fields)) el
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you. What my attempts were missing is the `UNNEST` part. Happily upvoted and selected this answer as the best. Please consider upvoting this question if you find it helpful and well-written