# Google Big Query - Extract keys from JSON string that are not explicitly marked as keys

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have the following JSON string (I added line breaks for visibility, in actual code all of it is squished in one line)

```
    {"schema":
       {"properties":
          {"key_1":{"label":"key 1","type":"string"},
           "key_2":{"label":"key 2","type":"string"},
           "ley_3":{"label":"key 3","type":"string"},
           "key_4":{"label":"key 4","type":"string"},
           ...
          } 
       }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is extract all keys and labels associated with the key. I know [how to do this when key is explicitly stated in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533836/how-to-query-specific-information-from-a-json-column), but in this example key is not explicitly stated.

I followed [Google Big Query documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract) on working with JSON strings, and here is how far I got:

```
SELECT json_schema, JSON_EXTRACT(json_schema, "$.schema.properties"), JSON_EXTRACT(json_schema, "$.schema.properties[1]")
FROM schemas
```

`json_schema` is a column name in the `schemas` table.

This gets me to the right direction, but I don't know how to proceed from here. My desired output is (for example), is:

```
key    value
key_1  key 1
key_2  key 2
key_3  key 3
key_4  key 4
```

Here is the code to reproduce the example:

```
SELECT '{"schema":{"properties":{"key_1":{"label":"key 1","type":"string"},"key_2":{"label":"key 2","type":"string"},"key_3":{"label":"key 3","type":"string"},"key 4":{"label":"key_4","type":"string"}}}}' AS json_schema
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select key, 
  json_extract_scalar(regexp_extract(props, r'"' || key || '":({.*?})'), '$.label') value
from your_table, 
unnest([struct(json_extract(json_schema, '$.schema.properties') as props)]),
unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys`(props)) key
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
   select '''
    {"schema":
       {"properties":
          {"key_1":{"label":"key 1","type":"string"},
           "key_2":{"label":"key 2","type":"string"},
           "ley_3":{"label":"key 3","type":"string"},
           "key_4":{"label":"key 4","type":"string"}
          } 
       }
    }
   ''' json_schema
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer Mikhail. I am AFK right now and will analyze this to make sure I understand everything in the code. Will happily upvote once I confirm this works and makes sense to me :handshake:

Comment: Mikhail, I am working on implementing your proposed solution. When I use your solution on the example I provided, it works well. When I apply this to my actual data, I am getting the following error message `Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group`. Will it help if I provide a full example I am working with?

Comment: Happily accepted this as the preferred answer and upvoted. Please consider upvoting the question if you believe it is helpful and is well formed